# Listening To Events from windows Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, service

Sorry if it is a basic question but I am new to Database polling

I am creating an ASP.net project in which we need to constantly monitors a database (MySQL) table and whenever any row is added in that table, we display that in UI. Now I have created a Windows Service which monitors that DB table and it generates an event when the table changes. Now How can get that notification in my ASP.net project from my windows service so that I can display in UI?

Comment: As ASP.NET projects are only executed on the web server while generating the HTML content for the client's browser, you'd have to implement something on the client side (for example a JavaScript that constantly uses an HTTP request to query a WebMethod [AJAX] or an UpdatePanel). You could also tell your page to refresh every now and then, but that's a pretty outdated way of doing this.

Comment: websockets would facilitate real-time web page updating.

Comment: @DaveDev Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the Windows service and implement the polling in the ASP.NET website itself. You said that you only want to show the new records on the website UI, so there's no reason for a service, which only introduces an unnecessary communication layer. You need to have your website constantly running anyway to do what you want, so you don't need that advantage of Windows services, which are generally used to keep stuff running.

Just make sure that your ASP.NET website is constantly running (`startMode = AlwaysRunning`) and has no idle timeout (`processModel.idleTimeout = TimeSpan.Zero`). I would use SignalR for the push notifications, so whenever you find a new row, you can send a message to clients and they can react to that immediately.